# Android - passing view id into AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a lot of buttons on main activity. Each button run this same `AsyncTask` which do HTTP POST method but post different values (which I store in `Button.Tag` property). So I have one `AsyncTask` for all buttons. Problem is when `AsyncTask` done his job, it should know which button must be updated in callback (button which execute `AsyncTask`). I don't want pass object (button instance) to `AsyncTask` because I read that activity can be recreated by system in many situations (orientation change, etc), so object passed to `AsyncTask` could be invalid. But what about `View.ID` property? It can be changed by system in activity life cycle too or can I use this integer value, pass it to `AsyncTask` and in `onPostExecute` find this button by this ID (calling `findViewByID`)?

Regards

Comment: you can use can  integer value but the problem is you still need activity reference to use findViewByID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your async task inside you activity as inner class you can use the integer id value in OnPostExecute by calling `findViewById(int id)`.

In other cases you to pass viewGroup which is holding your buttons.

Comment: This can result in a memory leak if the Activity is destroyed while the AsyncTask is in doInBackground. He would have to destroy the AsyncTask in the onDestroy method of his Activity.

Comment: I know that this answer has now been marked as accepted, but once again, I stress that this causes a memory leak, and can lead to unexpected functionality in the future. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033007/android-memory-leak-due-to-asynctask

Comment: If async task is inner class of activity everything will be OK. Leak can be caused only in case of passing viewGroup.

Comment: That's not true. Inner classes hold an implicit reference to their containing class, which is why findViewById would work from inside the AsyncTask. See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?InnerClass

Answer (score 2):

The id of an element can not be changed because it is generated by Android on the R.java. So you can use this value I think.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an observer within your AsyncTask that you can null when your Activity disappears.

Example

Activity:

```
private List<MyAsyncTask> mMyAsyncTasks;

private void addAsyncTask(MyAsyncTask task) {
    mMyAsyncTasks.add(task);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    for(MyAsyncTask task : mMyAsyncTasks) {
        task.removeObserver();
    }
}
```

Async Tasks:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Something, Something, Something> {
    private MyAsyncTaskObserver mObserver;
    private int mButtonId;

    public MyAsyncTask(MyAsyncTaskObserver observer, int buttonId) {
        mObserver = observer;
        mButtonId = buttonId;
    }

    public void removeObserver() {
        mObserver = null;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Something result) {
        ...
        if (mObserver != null) {
            mObserver.onMyDataAvailable(result, mButtonId);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your AsyncTask should not be inside your Activity, as it can result in a memory leak if your Activity is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea would be to pass a unique value that identifies a particular button.For instance if button1 is clicked pass 'button1' to the async task.In post execute we can use switch cases to update the desired button.As simple as that.

Edit:Better still use the [findViewWithTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag%28java.lang.Object%29) method to identify the button,since you are already sending a tag value to the asynctask.No need to use switch cases in this case

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you ensure your views all have unique identifiers, whether made in XML or code - and then call `findViewById(int id)` on your ViewGroup to get the correct view after your AsyncTask has finished (override `onPostExecute()` in AsyncTask to ensure you're on the UI thread).

EDIT: 
This is assuming you have created your AsyncTask in a fragment/activity and can call `getView()` on it to get your hierarchy.