# ListView is leaking activity context

Tags: android, listview, memory-leaks, leakcanary

The following code is leaking the activity context:

*This is actually inside an asyncTask in the onPostExecute*

```
ChatCustomAdapter customAdapter = new ChatCustomAdapter(mContext,   chatData, Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Helvetica-Bold.ttf"));
mChatList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

inside the adapter the context is used for

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
```

Am I holding a reference to the context? if so how do I release it?

LeakCanary is telling me that the ListView (mChatList) is leaking the context and if i remove setAdapter the leak has gone.

[image: LeakCanary screen shot]

Comment: What is 'Chat instance', is it a singleton that holds a reference to context? If so, there will be a leak.

Comment: @WenChao Chat is the activity which just displays a list using the adapter so i presumed that it is leaking the context for the Chat activity

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
You can try to wrap your `mChatList` with `WeakReference`, for exp:

```
class ChatTask extends AsyncTask {
  private WeakReference<ListView> mListRef;

  public ChatTask(ListView chatList) {
    mListRef = new WeakReference<ListView>(chatList);
  }

  public void onPostExecute() {
    ListView chatList = mListRef.get();
    if (chatList != null) {
        Context context = chatList.getContext();
        ChatCustomAdapter customAdapter = new ChatCustomAdapter(context, chatData, 
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/Helvetica-Bold.ttf"));
        chatList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
  }
}
```

If it still not work, you could try to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033007/android-memory-leak-due-to-asynctask)

---

I assume that you create the `inflater` inside the `ChatCustomAdapter` constructor and keep that `inflater` as global variable to use later in `getView` method? 
If that true, I think you should try to remove the variable `inflater` and inside `getView` method, create a local `inflater` by `LayoutInflater.from(parentView.getContext);`
Hope that helps.

Comment: i definitely like this and thought it had fixed it but my leak must be else where as it is still leaking i will update the question now with the LeakCanary screen shot

Comment: i have added the screen shot does it make more sense to you ?

Comment: @Rob85 I updated the answer, pls check if it could help.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, i have found the cause, maybe you can explain better as i don't understand it - see my answer

Comment: @Rob85, Sorry, the leak will depend on how you store the variable `mContext` and `ChatButton`, from just the code you reveal, I cannot found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i have found the problem but i do not understand it so maybe some can comment and explain or answer with why it does this. the leak was in the Chat activity. to get to the Chat activity i have a button in the previous activity:

```
    ChatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Chat.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

when i start the activity i was starting it from

```
mContext.startActivity(intent)
```

if i change this to just

```
startActivity(intent);
```

it doesn't leak.

**Edit**

it does still leak